# Getting Exceptions during KafkaTest eventhough the test passes

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am running a Junit test using EmbeddedKafka,I am able to produce and consume to the embeddedKafka brokers, and successfully assert the data i have send.

But i can see a lot of exceptions in the stack trace, which comes after the assertion is done.

1)

java.io.IOException: Connection to 0 was disconnected before the response was read
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.sendAndReceive(NetworkClientUtils.java:97) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:240) ~[kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:82) [kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]

2)

2019-10-04 15:49:27.123  WARN 1812 --- [r-0-send-thread] kafka.controller.RequestSendThread       : [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Controller 0's connection to broker localhost:54745 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Failed to connect within 1000 ms
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:280) [kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:233) [kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:82) [kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]

3)

java.io.IOException: Connection to localhost:54745 (id: 0 rack: null) failed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:70) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:279) [kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:233) [kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:82) [kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]

4)

java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.pause(ShutdownableThread.scala:69) [kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.backoff$1(ControllerChannelManager.scala:221) ~[kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:235) ~[kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:82) [kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar:na]

My Test:

```
 import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Header;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Headers;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
    import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
    import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
    import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
    import org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.EmbeddedKafkaRule;

    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = TestApplication.class)
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
    //@EmbeddedKafka(controlledShutdown = true)
    public class KafkaUtilTest {

        private static String TOPIC = "PE";

        @Autowired
        KafkaUtil kafkaUtil;

        @Autowired
        ConfigurationProperties configProperties;

        SchedulingCallRequestDTO request;
        ScheduleOrderResponseDTOv2 response;
        Consumer<String, Object> consumer;
        HashMap<String, String> expectedHeaderValueMap;

        @ClassRule
        public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafkarule = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, TOPIC);

        @BeforeClass
        public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
            System.setProperty("spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers",
                    embeddedKafkarule.getEmbeddedKafka().getBrokersAsString());
        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void tearDown() {
            embeddedKafkarule.getEmbeddedKafka().getKafkaServers().forEach(b -> b.shutdown());
            embeddedKafkarule.getEmbeddedKafka().getKafkaServers().forEach(b -> b.awaitShutdown());
        }

        @Before
        public void init() {
            readFile("0211");
            expectedHeaderValueMap = getExpectedHeaderValueMap();
            Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs = new HashMap<>(
                    KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("consumer", "true", embeddedKafkarule.getEmbeddedKafka()));
            consumerConfigs.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            consumerConfigs.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
            consumerConfigs.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "com.adessa.promiseengine.dto.kafka");

            consumer = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Object>(consumerConfigs).createConsumer();

            List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
            topics.add(TOPIC);

            TopicPartition topicPartition1 = new TopicPartition(TOPIC, 0);
            TopicPartition topicPartition2 = new TopicPartition(TOPIC, 1);
            List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = new ArrayList<TopicPartition>();
            topicPartitions.add(topicPartition1);
            topicPartitions.add(topicPartition2);
            consumer.assign(topicPartitions);
            consumer.seekToBeginning(topicPartitions);

        }

        @Test
        public void testPublish() throws Exception {
            kafkaUtil.publishToKafka(request, response);
            kafkaUtil.kafkaTemplate.flush();
            ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumedRecord = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer, TOPIC);
            assertRecord(consumedRecord);
        }
        private void readFile(String testSequenceNo) {}

    }
```

Why are these exceptions there? And during what process they are occuring? Please help

Comment: Please show your tests.

Comment: I have added the test.Please have a look @GaryRussell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a class rule and the broker is torn down when the test completes, but you are leaving the consumer open; you need to close the consumer at the end of the test.